# What is the proper way to seed a 3 node cluster?

Tags: cassandra

A little background if it helps, I'm preparing a 3 node cluster (all in the same rackspace). I want 3 nodes for optimal consistency and resilience in the smallest footprint and I am not concerned with replicating the cluster to another region.

One question I have is regarding seed nodes. I know that it is not a good idea to make every node in your cluster a seed, but in the case of 3 nodes, should I just go ahead and do that? Or should I just make a subset of the three nodes seed nodes? Confused as to how pick how many or which ones (all the machines are identical so which ones probably isn't an issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seed nodes are nothing special but an initial contact point address. Best practice is to have 1 seed node per 3 nodes in the cluster but this varies depending on the deployment. You can also put all three IPs in the seed node list without any problems.

Comment: From DataStax: "Note: It is a best practice to have more than one seed node per datacenter." I take this to mean, 2 seeds for a 3-node cluster. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommanded to make all nodes seed nodes when initializing a multiple node cluster.

> Determine which nodes will be seed nodes. Do not make all nodes seed nodes. Please read Internode communications (gossip).

Although it is best practice to have 1 seed per 3 nodes in the cluster, it is also best practice to have multiple seeds for one data center when you configure your cluster.

> Note: It is a best practice to have more than one seed node per datacenter.

I suggest you make 2 seed out of your 3 nodes. Let us know what option you went for.

Answer (score 0):

[Internode communications (gossip)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archGossipAbout.html)The seed node designation has no purpose other than bootstrapping the gossip process for new nodes joining the cluster. Seed nodes are not a single point of failure, nor do they have any other special purpose in cluster operations beyond the bootstrapping of nodes.

Making every node a seed node is not recommended because of increased maintenance and reduced gossip performance. Gossip optimization is not critical, but it is recommended to use a small seed list.

So the best practice is setting 1 seed node for a 3 node cluster.